# Protege Incremental inference and complementOf

Tags: owl, protege

Please I have two questions ;
Q1: I have implemented the  ChildlessPerson  class in Protege 5.5.0 and defined an individual of type person with no haschild property. I tried with Hermet, Pellet, ontop, none derives that the individual is a ChildlessPerson.

```
:ChildlessPerson rdf:type OWL:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type OWL:Class ; OWL:intersectionOf ( :Person
                    [ rdf:type OWL:Class ;
                      OWL:complementOf [ rdf:type OWL:Restriction ;
                                    OWL:onProperty :hasChild ; OWL:someValuesFrom OWL:Thing]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ] ) ] .
```

Q2 : In the ontology I have Parent subclassOf Person and Father subclassOf Parent. I defined an individual of typefather, it is inferred that it is a parent, but the fact that is a person is not inferred. I checked also with Pellet incremental. Why ?

:Father rdf:type OWL:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf :Parent; OWL:disjointWith :Mother.
:Mother rdf:type OWL:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf :Parent.
:Parent rdf:type OWL:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf  :Person.
:Person: rdf:type OWL:Class ; rdfs:comment "Represents the set of all people."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q1: Please read about *Open World Assumption*

Comment: Q2: not sure what you're asking but "Person subclassOf Parent and Parent subclassOf Father" do not make sense to me. I guess you mixed up the direction.

Comment: Q1: you need equivalentClass instead of subClassOf to be able to derive that some individual is a childless person. OWA may also be an issue.

Comment: We cannot answer question 2 without seeing the ontology.

Comment: `:Father SubClassOf :Person` will definitely be inferred with Pellet or any other OWL reasoner in Protege. The question is where in the UI you expect it to be shown but don't find it?